# jQuery selector by a, class, href

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML block

```
<a class="active" href="#mobileOrder">
```

I am using `jQuery 2.1.1` . When I click the above block, I want call JavaScript

```
function move(){...}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Simply do like:

```
$("a.active[href='#mobileOrder']").on("click", move);
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/